# Swift Ui Есть 4 слайдера для углов View при попытке изменить радиус угла то сбрасывается другой?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Есть 4 слайдера для каждого угла View и 4 action которые изменяют радиус угла но при каждом выполнения Action сбрасывается значения которые уже были изменены Почему так происходит ? т.е я могу изменить радиус только одного угла потому что изменения сбрасываются в исходном состоянии

вот 4 Асtion

```
@IBAction func left_top_cornier_slider_action(_ sender: UISlider) {
    viewControlIBO.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner]
    viewControlIBO.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(left_top_cornier_slider.value)
}
@IBAction func right_top_cornier_slider_action(_ sender: UISlider) {
    viewControlIBO.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    viewControlIBO.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(right_top_cornier_slider.value)
}
@IBAction func right_down_cornier_slider_action(_ sender: UISlider) {
    viewControlIBO.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    viewControlIBO.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(right_down_cornier_slider.value)
}
@IBAction func left_down_cornier_slider_action(_ sender: UISlider) {
    viewControlIBO.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner]
    viewControlIBO.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(left_down_cornier_slider.value)
}
```

Вот UI
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что в каждой функции у вас прописан только один угол, остальные сбрасываются, соответственно.

Comment: И вы не сможете маской установить разные радиусы углов, смотрите в сторону UIBezierPath

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Для UIKit единственный выход - использовать `UIBezierPath`

Ответ есть в англоязычном сообществе, вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128198/12806988)

При использовании `UIBezierPath` нужно быть аккуратным, если верстка использует `NSLayoutConstraint`, потому, что они вычисляются динамически